# Проверка директории, на совпадение с другой директорией

Tags: php

Как осуществить проверку директории,на совпадение с другой директорией?

Answer (score 0):

Сравнить полные их пути, например.

```
if ( realpath($dir1) == realpath($dir2) ) {}
```

Запускаемый скрипт должен иметь права запуска на всех директориях в проверяемой иерархии, иначе realpath() вернет FALSE.